# Using global name in a nested function

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, nested, global

As I understand the global statement in the code below, it should prevent function_two from rebinding the name test and instead modify test in function_one.  However, I get NameError: global name 'test' is not defined.

```
def function_one():
    test = 1
    def function_two():
        global test
        test += 1
    function_two()
    print test
function_one()
```

I have looked and I can't find an example like this.  What am I missing?

Comment: You misunderstood. `global` does not mean the same thing as `nonlocal` (Python 3 only). `global` really means *global*, e.g. *not in a function*. `test` in `function_two` expects there to be a global name `test`; the local name `test` in `function_one()` is ignored.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? Presumably Python 2, since you use `print` as a statement.

Comment: You don't need `global` to access to `test` from `function_two`, just `test += 1` would be enough

Comment: @name_no: no, that'll not work. You'll get a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'test' referenced before assignment` exception.

Comment: Related: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/

Comment: What is the point of this? Just pass it to the function. That's what functions DO!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist what if the goal of `function_one() is to produce `function_two()` to be called by other code later?  Closures do have use cases not easily covered by other techniques.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It doesn't return `function_two`. I'm wondering if there's a need for closures here at all.

Comment: Yes, it is code without a purpose.  I just wanted a simple example that demonstrated my confusion with the global statement.  The answers were very enlightening.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: this is a demo setup. Use `return function_two()` and add an extra `()` to the `function_one()` call to make it `function_one()()`. There, now you need a closure. This is hardly the point of the question though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python 2 does not support the concept of a *non-local*. Closures (accessing `test` from a parent function) only support *read access*, not assignment in Python 2.

The `global` keyword really does mean *global*, e.g. that the name lives in the module (global) namespace. The namespace of the `function_one()` function is not global, it is local (to that function).

In Python 3, you can mark a name as [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement), which would make your example work as expected. See [PEP 3104 - *Access to Names in Outer Scopes*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/).

In Python 2, you'll have to resort to tricks instead. Make the name an attribute of the nested function, for example. 'reading' the function object as a closure is allowed, as is setting attributes on such closed-over objects:

```
def function_one():
    def function_two():
        function_two.test += 1

    function_two.test = 1
    function_two()

    print test
```

Another trick is to use a *mutable* object, such as a list or a dictionary. Again, you are only *reading* the closed-over name, then altering the resulting object directly:

```
def function_one():
    test = [1]

    def function_two():
        test[0] += 1

    function_two()

    print test[0]
```